# Edit an existing exported csv file via PHP / Laravel and re-save

Tags: php, laravel, csv, export-to-csv, laravel-excel

I am using Laravel-Excel to export a CSV file with a header and footer row. The header and footer rows only have 2-3 columns, however body rows have multiple additional columns - resulting in additional trailing commas at the end of the header and footer.

Since the Laravel-Excel package cannot remove these additional commas, I need to, once the file has been exported, open it somehow via the code, remove the trailing commas from the header and footer rows and then re-save the file and let my users download the end result.

So what I am looking for is:

Actual:

```
Header,20211021,065529,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Footer,49,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Required:

```
Header,20211021,065529
Footer,49
```

So the process would be as follows:

1. Generate the export file using Laravel-Excel
2. Save the generated file to the server
3. Open the generated file, determine the last line
4. Remove the trailing commas from line 1 (header)
5. Remove the trailing commas from the last line (footer)
6. Overwrite/save the existing csv file

Any help on how I would go about this would be hugely helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to reach this is using simple php. Via `rtrim` its very easy to accomplish this:

```php
$contents = file('file.csv');
foreach ($contents as &$line) {
    $line = rtrim($line, ",\r\n");
}
file_put_contents('file.csv', implode("\n", $contents));
```

Comment: This is perfect! Is there a way though that I can only trim the first and last lines of the file?

Comment: Instead of foreach do it with `$contents[0]` and `$contents[count($contents) - 1]`